# White bar appears when iPhone changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, cordova

[iPhone image with white bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttpvo.png)  I'm experiencing an issue with the display of an Angular 6 app with Cordova on iOS devices in landscape mode. The app looks as expected in portrait mode, however when the orientation is changed to landscape a white bar appears on the screen in the top half left corner.

I've tried adding and removing 'viewport-fit=cover' and there's no change. 
I also tried debugging the app in Safari using the 'Develop' option and the white bar is not affected by any styling and I can't even inspect the bar ... it's like it doesn't exist in code but appears on the device somehow.

I expect to not see the white bar at the top of the screen when the iPhone device is in landscape mode.
What am I missing? Is this an iOS/Apple issue? Or an issue with Cordova?

Comment: From what I remember, `viewport-fit=cover` interacts with a few other CSS / `<meta>` tags on iOS. There's a webkit blog entry here that explains them a bit better: https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/.

That said, you could be running into a UIWebView rendering bug: https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/18415